# JSON parse issue in Titanium

Tags: json, parsing, titanium, tableview, titanium-mobile

I am working on simple task read the data from url which is in  JSON format and display those fields in Table

i written code like as

```
var Win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;  
//SEARCH BAR
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

tableData=[];
Win.open();
xhr.onload = function() {
    alert('res'+this.responseData);
     var json = this.responseText;
    var response = JSON.parse(json);
    //-- Mail was sent
    alert('respoinse length : '+response.result.length);
   tableData=[];
    for (i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++) {
            sresult = response.result[i];
            //alert('City'+ sresult.city);


            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                rowID: i,
                color:'#222',


    left:70, top:44,
    width:360,


                text:sresult.County
            });
            tableData.push(row);
        }

      table.setData(tableData);  


};

var table = Titanium.UI.createTableView({

        top:60,
        data:tableData

   });
    Win.add(table);
//xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.clia.livestockid.ca/CLTS/public/division/CCIA/en/splash_logo.jpg');
xhr.open('GET', 'http://gomashup.com/json.php?fds=geo/usa/zipcode/city/STERLING');
xhr.send();
```

i run it on Titanium - the first alert showing the JSON data. after that its not getting alert of second one not sure ... why its not moving to next step... please help me on this is there any mistakes in code or else parsing issue.

Thanks
Devendar

Comment: Do you see any errors reported? What does the JSON look like? Usually the problem when people ask this question is that the JSON is malformed.

Comment: Go with That Url friend "http://gomashup.com/json.php?fds=geo/usa/zipcode/city/STERLING"

Comment: @ Devendar: No, that's not now it works (not least because the result can **change** over time, rendering the question useless to anyone in the future). Quote the JSON **in the question itself**>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "JSON" returned by the url you gave (`http://gomashup.com/json.php?fds=geo/usa/zipcode/city/STERLING`) is invalid. (http://jsonlint.com is a useful resource for checking that sort of thing.) It starts with a `(` and ends with a `)`, like this:

```
({
    "result":[
    {
        "Longitude" : "-071.939375",
        "Zipcode" : "01564",
        "ZipClass" : "STANDARD",
        "County" : "WORCESTER",
        "City" : "STERLING",
        "State" : "MA",
        "Latitude" : "+42.366765"
    }
]}
)
```

*(I've omitted a lot from that.)*

[JSON documents](http://json.org) start with either `[` or `{`, and end with the corresponding `]` or `}`.

The above would be valid without the `(` at the beginning and `)` at the end, so you could always remove them before parsing, but the real answer is to fix the feed.

Comment: ho i am using invalid JSON... Friend any valid JSON url for test myself please provide me

Comment: @Devendar: If this is just test data, it's *trivial* to create your own.

Comment: Friend why you did downvote for my question... i am a new one for JSON .. i am a trainee

Comment: .. even i used good JSON file also not able to get - http://api.androidhive.info/contacts

Comment: @Devendar: Votes on SO are anonymous. You should never assume that just because someone comments on your question, and someone downvotes the question, that the same person did both things. It's actually quite rare.